# Preventing loss of funds from a hacked eos account?

Tags: stake-pools, hacked-account, active-key, owner-key

I've read that to secure your funds, you can stake your eos and then if it gets compromised, the hacker has to unstake which takes 3 days.

From then, you can switch out the active and owner key? (is this right?)

But my question is how do you know if your eos account is compromised in the first place if you don't login to the wallet every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the telegram bot or have this service send you an email whenever something happens:

https://eosauthority.com/alerts

Then you can take action.